# Increase text size as I scroll past it then decrease as I keep scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want text to increase in size (or opacity) as it approaches the middle of the screen and then decrease size (or opacity) as it gets scrolled past. I've attached two images showing what I want to do.

I have tried the animate on scroll library but I don't think it has the functionality I want.

Example of how I want to increase opacity.

[image: Example of how I want to increase opacity]

Example of how I want to increase size.

[image: Example of how I want to increase size]

Comment: Measure the window then do the math onscroll. You may want to see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

Comment: Really, I would use [window.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) adding in your top border and margin. Then use [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) onscroll to get where your Element is, since it gives you the viewport position.